# Timespan.FromHours for decimal conversion

Tags: c#, timespan

I am using `TimeSpan.FromHours(9.30)` which gives "09:18:00" and If I use `TimeSpan.Parse("09:30")` then it will return 09:30. Both are same but `TimeSpan.FromHours` is a lot safer and more efficient.

Please advice why result is different?

Thanks,

Comment: `FromHours` is **not** "h.mm" , it is fractions of hours. So you want `TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5)` (Think "9 hours and a half") See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromhours?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `0.3` of 60 is `18`. In your case, `09.30` needs to be changed to `9.5`.

Comment: Mind: While FromHours takes a Double, it will only be accurate to the nearest Millisecond (see docs linked above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromHours` is **not** of the format "h.mm", it is fractions of hours.

So you want `TimeSpan.FromHours(9.5)` (Think "9 hours and a half")

See also: [TimeSpan.FromHours(Double)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromhours?view=netframework-4.8)

Mind: While `FromHours` takes a Double, it will only be accurate to the nearest Millisecond

[`TimeSpan.Parse(String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netframework-4.8) takes a time interval (heads up: dependend on system culture *) ), so here you have for example "09:30" as actually 9 hours, 30 minutes.

*) "dependend on system culture" means: "5.123" would be 5 seconds, 123 millis in US Culture, but would throw an exception in cultures that use "," as decimal separator. For details see linked docs.